# Subform data manipulation using queries

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, subform

[image: Calendar]

I am developing a customized calendar on access. The image above is a snippet of what im trying to do, each "box" is a subform of a form [cell] that is linked to a table that has appointments as entries. I want all subforms under monday to each show an appointment for Monday and same for Tuesday and so on to have a weekly appointment calendar. I must point out that all these subforms are of the same form [cell] I just want them to show different records.

I have been trying to update/change data on load in the subforms with no success, its giving me an sql statement error, doesnt recognize its an sql statement.

Also I dont want to have an SQL statement for each subform as it will be 25(5 subforms per day) sql queries running and im sure it will really slowdown the program. How can I make it more efficient, use less sql statements. Here is my initial code for the first cell

```
Dim sqlstring As String
sqlstring = "SELECT CallB_Schedule.InternName, CallB_Schedule.ClientName,              CallB_Schedule.ClientPhone, CallB_Schedule.Time FROM CallB_Schedule WHERE  (WEEKDAY(CallB_Schedule.InternName) = 2)"
DoCmd.RunSQL (sqlstring)
Forms!Schedule!schedule_cell_monday.Form!InternName = InternName
Forms!Schedule!schedule_cell_monday.Form!Time = Time
Forms!Schedule!schedule_cell_monday.Form!ClientName = ClientName
Forms!Schedule!schedule_cell_monday.Form!ClientPhone = ClientPhone
```

Where Schedule is the main form and schedule_cell_monday is one of the subforms on Schedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the recordsource of the sub form in the code you have given.  You could replace

```
DoCmd.RunSQL (sqlstring)
```

with

```
Forms!Schedule!schedule_cell_monday.Form.recordsource = sqlstring
```

The code to run the sql statement is often reserved for action queries.

Comment: that was part of my dilemma how to "assign" the values from my record to each text box in my subform. Thanks ill try that! Also is the SQL statement fine? gave me an error when called by RunSQL, even if its not how I want to use it, it should run fine.

Comment: when you use the sql statement in a query do you get results?  That is normally how I debug my sql scripts.